# pass parameters in a system void - visual c++

Tags: c++-cli

how can I pass other parameters in this void?

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
```

I tried adding this parameters:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e,  MySqlDataAdapter ^data, DataSet ^dataset)
```

but the compiler gives me:

Error   1   error C3352: 'void loadprocedura::Form1::button1_Click(System::Object ^,System::EventArgs ^,MySql::Data::MySqlClient::MySqlDataAdapter ^,System::Data::DataSet ^)' : the specified function does not match the delegate type 'void (System::Object ^,System::EventArgs ^)'

then I tried adding here that parameters, but doesn't work

```
this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button1_Click);
```

I'm a beginner in visual c++ ;)

Comment: Since you're a beginner, you should be aware that you are *not* using the real C++, you are using a Microsoft language called [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI), which is quite different.

Answer (score 0):

`button1->Click accepts` a certain kind of delegate:

```
void (System::Object ^,System::EventArgs ^)
```

If you want to trigger the event manually, you can just add parameters to the `System::EventArgs` object.

You should read a tutorial about C# events:

[MSDN Events Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)